# Heroku subdomains, one app, different url-paths

Tags: http, heroku, dns

I have heroku app ie my-app.herokuapp.com. This is Java application which is deployed on jetty

What I want get is transparent http traffic dispatch - without redirects (no 3xx statuses).

I have domain xyz.com, want configure something like this:

- xyz.com/* -> my-app.herokuapp.com/*
- **api**.xyz.com/* -> my-app.herokuapp.com/**api**/*

Does it possible to configure heroku in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some rewrite rules to map requests for that domain. You can point both domains to the same heroku domain with DNS. I wouldn't recommend using a naked root domain, but you could use www.xyz.com.

```
$ heroku domains:add www.xyz.com
$ heroku domains:add api.xyz.com
```

And in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.xyz.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: I'm making a big assumption you are using Apache, as nothing was noted about the stack. Same principles apply though

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using jetty (java - application on heroku). I'll switch to use only subdomains as you recommend.